# PHP array sub arrays and array_keys confusion

Tags: php, arrays

I have a $menus array which contains $submenu arrays which then contain $sub_submenu arrays.

The structure is something like this:

```
(
    [0] => Menu 0
        [0] => Sub Menu 0 of Menu 0
            [0] => Sub Sub Menu 0 of Sub Menu 0 of Menu 0
            [1] => Sub Sub Menu 1 of Sub Menu 0 of Menu 0
        [1] => Sub Menu 1 of Menu 0
            [0] => Sub Sub Menu 0 of Sub Menu 1 of Menu 0
            [1] => Sub Sub Menu 1 of Sub Menu 1 of Menu 0
    [1] => Menu 1
        [0] => Sub Menu 0 of Menu 1
            [0] => Sub Sub Menu 0 of Sub Menu 0 of Menu 1
            [1] => Sub Sub Menu 1 of Sub Menu 0 of Menu 1
        [1] => Sub Menu 1 of Menu 1
            [0] => Sub Sub Menu 0 of Sub Menu 1 of Menu 1
            [1] => Sub Sub Menu 1 of Sub Menu 1 of Menu 1
)
```

if I try this:

```
echo $menus[$menu[1]][$submenu[0]][1];
```

I get:

```
Sub Sub Menu 1 of Sub Menu 0 of Menu 1
```

which is what I expect.

I am now trying create an array which contains the values of the sub_sub_menu KEYS and I thought I could just do this:

```
$sub_sub_menu = array_keys($menus[$menu[1]][$submenu[0]]);
```

but I get an empty array instead:

```
echo '<pre>';print_r($sub_sub_menu); echo '</pre>';
```

returns this:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 4
    [5] => 5
    [6] => 6
    [7] => 7
    [8] => 8
    [9] => 9
)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: in the way you have been posted your array isn't easy to read, use this to convert the array to readable form http://phpoverflow.eu01.aws.af.cm/print_r/

Comment: @EmilioGort not sure what you mean. You want me to post something in that form and post it back here?

Answer (score 0):

You stated that you "... get an empty array instead:" from the array_keys() function

but the result you showed:

```
   Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 4
    [5] => 5
    [6] => 6
    [7] => 7
    [8] => 8
    [9] => 9
)
```

is not an empty array, but rather appears to be populated with the keys of a numerically indexed array (which is what we may expect when running array_keys on a non-associative array).

It would be nice if  you included a dump of an actual array as created in your program so that we can have a better idea of what it really looks like.

It may also help if you let us know what you are planning on using the array of keys for (is it for displaying the menu items to the user for instance?)

Comment: that result is actually the output of the print_r function and yes I am trying to show the sub sub menu value to the user

Comment: i apologize i meant an actual dump of the menus array [not of the array_keys() output].  it appears that you may be storing the sub sub menu options as the $menu arrays values (not the arrays keys).  so using array_value() instead may work for you. that or $sub_sub_menu = $menus[$menu[1]][$submenu[0]] for example.  I cant know for sure though without seeing the actual $menus array.